# Standardized effect sizes interpretation using emmeans

Tags: r, emmeans

I used eff_size() function to calculate effect sized of conditions of a lmer object.
However, I can't find a rule of thumb for interpreting the effect size. Any guidelines or suggestions?

Many thanks!

```
> eff_size(post, sigma = sigma(fit), edf = df.residual(fit))
 contrast  effect.size     SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 1_1 - 1_3     -0.3418 0.0580 68.7  -0.4575  -0.2261
 1_1 - 3_1     -0.3987 0.0579 68.7  -0.5143  -0.2831
 1_1 - 3_3     -0.1518 0.0575 68.7  -0.2666  -0.0371
 1_3 - 3_1     -0.0569 0.0582 69.2  -0.1730   0.0593
 1_3 - 3_3      0.1900 0.0580 68.7   0.0742   0.3058
 3_1 - 3_3      0.2468 0.0579 68.7   0.1312   0.3624

sigma used for effect sizes: 0.3014 
Degrees-of-freedom method: inherited from kenward-roger when re-gridding 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Comment: They are just estimates of the differences, divided by the sigma you specified, AKA Cohen's d. Some people think these are meaningful, and I think they use Cohen's concepts of small, medium, and large effects. I think medium is 0.40.

Comment: I would add that it appears your model is a mixed model. That means there are multiple sources of random variation. And that means you have to take care to identify which population the effect sizes apply to. You used the residual SD for sigma, and that's probably the wrong choice. Look in the vignette topics index for prediction for examples of how to get the total SD from a mixed model.

Comment: Many thanks Professor. If correctly understood SD tot is random effects SDs + residual SD and then square root.

Comment: Read it again, you square them before adding, then square root. It's like the Pythagorean Theorem.

Comment: @RussLenth: How do I calculate SD tot in case of correlated random effects (intercept and slope)? `VarCorr()` returns SD's for both and also their correlation. Do I also square the correlation and then substract that from the sum of squared SD's before taking the square root of the whole term, as the correlation represents common variance? I.e. would it be correct to do sqrt(SD(intercept)^2+SD(slope)^2-r^2)? Many thanks!

Comment: The correct way to combine two correlated SDs s1 and s2 would be sqrt(s1^2 + s2^2 + 2r*s1*s2). But you need the SD of the *response* and if you have a slope and an intercept, you need to also account for the value of the *x* variable that multiplies the slope; that is, you need SD(A + Bx) = sqrt(s1^2 + (s2*x)^2 + 2*r*s1*x*s2). emmeans really doesn't provide a user interface for bias-correction in models with random slopes.